# Clipping out left-out region of an MKOverlayView after intersection with another one

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am working with MapKit.
I draw OverlayView as Circles on the Map.
If I have a Circle overlay-view intersecting with another one such that smaller one's center inside the the bigger circular overlay.

Now I need to display only that part of the smaller overlayView that is intersecting with the bigger circular overlay view and not the entire circle.

How should I go about it ?

What I am trying now is to subclass MKOverLayPathView and create a Path between the two arcs on the intersection points.

For this I am doing a lot of trigonometrical calculations to find the correct arc angles and all.
I wanted to know if there is a simpler way to clip put the remaining part of the circular view because I am getting this feeling that I might be doing complicated stuff unnecessarily.